# 'NotLike: is not working with or condition in Casewhen MYsQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I tried to seperate the Normaldiscount for VIPmembersand 50% OFF but the NormalDiscount is showing all the discounts including VIP and 50% OFF. I am not sure why the NOT LIKE is not working with 'OR'. Any way to make it work ?

Here is my code

```sql
SELECT a.recid,
       a.name as TypeOfDisc,
       case when    a.name NOT like '%VIP%' 
                 OR a.name  NOT like ('50\\% OFF')  
            then a.qty*a.price 
            else 0 
            end as NormalDisc,
       case when    a.name like('%VIP%')
                 or a.name like('50\\% OFF First App Order') 
            then a.qty*a.price 
            end as VIpDisc
from sale a
where a.plo ='-1' 
  and a.date between ('2021-11-22') and ('2021-11-28')
```

Comment: Provide sample data (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 3-5 rows) and desired output for this data.

Comment: NOT like '%VIP%'  is NOT like ('50\\% OFF')   so evaluates to true when  '%VIP%' is encountered you probably need AND in your first case..